# Prove the least square solution is $\bar{x}=\bar{0}$

Tags: linear-algebra

> **Question:**
>
> Prove that if $A$ has linearly independent column vectors and if $\bar{b}$ is orthogonal to the column space of $A$, then the least-squares solution $A\bar{x}= \bar{b}$ is $\bar{x}=\bar{0}$.

Can someone please provide me with any hints as to how I can go about proving this?

**My attempt so far:**

Let $A$ be a matrix with linearly independent column vectors and $\bar{b}$ orthogonal to the column space of $A$.

Now consider the equation
\begin{align}A \bar{x} &= \bar{b} \\ \implies A^TA\bar{x} &= A^T\bar{b} \end{align}

Let $\bar{u_i}$ be the column vectors of $A$, where $i=1,2,\dots ,n$ then

\begin{align} A^TA\bar{x} & = \begin{bmatrix} \left \langle \bar{u}_1,\bar{b} \right \rangle \\
\left \langle \bar{u}_2, \bar{b}\right \rangle \\
\vdots \\
\left \langle \bar{u}_n, \bar{b} \right \rangle
\end{bmatrix} \end{align}

Now we know that $\left \langle \bar{u}_i, \bar{b}\right \rangle =0$ for all $i$, since $\bar{b}$ is orthogonal to the column space of $A$.

Thus our equation reduces to

\begin{align}A^TA\bar{x} &= \bar{0} \\
(A^TA)^{-1} A^TA &= (A^TA)^{-1}\bar{0} \\
\implies I\bar{x} &= \bar{0} \\
\implies \bar{x} &= \bar{0}
\end{align}

Comment: Multiply $A^T$ on both sides of the equation.

Comment: @freak_warrior - I edited it, but now I am stuck again and need some help ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Suppose $A$ has columns $a_1,\cdots,a_n$. Then
$$
A^T b = 
\pmatrix{
\langle a_1,b\rangle\\
\langle a_2,b\rangle\\
\vdots\\
\langle a_n,b\rangle
}
$$

Comment: Thank you! I edited what I have so far, but I am now stuck on the case where $A$ is not a square matrix ...

Comment: $x=0$ will always be a solution. The solution will be unique because $A^TAx=0 \implies Ax=0$. $Ax=0$ has only the trivial solution exactly when $A$ has linearly independent columns.

Comment: I tried showing it algebraically... Edited it now. Is it correct?

Comment: How do you know that $A^TA$ has an inverse?

Comment: Good point! Thank you for pointing that out ... Is there a way we can deduce that it is invertible?

Comment: There's usually a statement in the textbook to that effect. You could also directly show what I said above.